# javascript - setTimeout not firing after window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm facing a weird problem with setTimeout function! i have two html page as following:

**Index.html: **

```
<script>
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/s/s1.html';
var x ;

function closeTab() {
    try {
        console.log('trying...');
        x.close();
        console.log('closed!');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('cannot close tab!', e);
    }
};

x = window.open(url,'_blank');
setTimeout(closeTab, 3000);
</script>
```

and

**s1.html :**

```
<script>
alert(1);
</script>
```

The problem is after alert dialog showed in s1.html, the parent window (index.html) cannot close child tab via **closeTab** function, until user close the alert dialog! I want to (force) close it after 3000 milliseconds. even i searched for an alternative function for setTimeout but some solutions makes browser freezed.

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use an `alert()` which is modal?

Comment: @A.Wolff i have no controll over the s1.html. this could be any website on internet. this is just an example. Thanks